# Creating a floor plan table layout for restaurants HTML

Tags: html, layout, canvas, html5-canvas

We want to give options to users of an application to create floor layouts - not much of a detail, but to place tables around that could be recognizable for them. The layout once created needs to be stored in the database, recalled later. Also, by clicking a table, we should be able redirect user to a different page or scree.

Any leads? Ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow deals mainly with coding related questions. So you might ask your question on Stackoverflow's new sister site that deals with software recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is a coding related question - using Canvas or some jquery framework. I am not really asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: "It is a coding related question" -- Well...ok...but...you have given no code for us to fix?  Anyway, a typical basic floorplan app would involve either: (1) HTML+CSS+jQueryUI with jQueryUI for user interfacing, or (2) HTML+Svg with svg for user interfacing, or (3) HTML+Canvas+3rd Party Canvas Library with that Lib for user interfacing.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Can you also share some links that I can take some leads from? Sorry, I get it now about StackExchange, but it doesn't let me tag html5 or svg or canvas.

Comment: http://openfloorplan.org/